# Given Sequence of Numbers find number of combinations

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

I have the sequence of numbers $1,2,4,8,16,\ldots$. This is an infinite sequence. So my problem is that if I have any positive integer value, $x$, what are the possible ways that I can write $x$ as the sum of the sequence that I noted above.

For example, if $x=7$, then I would have the possible ways to be

- $1+1+1+1+1+1+1$
- $1+1+1+1+1+2$
- $1+1+1+2+2$
- $1+1+1+4$
- $1+2+2+2$
- $1+2+4$

So in this when $x=7$ we have $6$ possible ways. So basically, my question is that is there a way to generalize this for any value of $x$? Does it even exist? If it is necessary to note, when $x=10$ there are $14$ possible ways.

Comment: Is there some context for your question?

Comment: @ChrisRamsey: There's no context. I was looking at https://oeis.org/A018819, and I looked at the example and I wanted to know if we can generalize this. I am having a hard time understanding what that webpage is saying.

Comment: That page contains your answer. Under the section titled formula there is an easy recursive formula.

Comment: @ChrisRamsey I saw that: "a(2m+1) = a(2m), a(2m) = a(2m-1) + a(m)" Right? Can you show me how this works when x=7 case?

Comment: The proof is written immediately after. Fyi, this question should be asked on math.stackexchange as math overflow is for professional-level mathematics.

Comment: Does order matter or no?

Answer (score 1):

If order matters then what you are describing are called binary partitions https://oeis.org/A000123 and are generated by

$$
f(x) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^{2^n})
$$
You can get to your situation by dividing every part by two.  Hence the number of binary partitions of $2n$ with parts starting at $2,4,8\dots$ is the same as the number of binary partitions of $n$ with parts starting at $1,2,4,8\dots.$

If not I would call them binary compositions but I don't think they have a name. You can generate them by looking at the sequence

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2^n}}
$$